# Macro loops to create a large number of variables at pre-processing

Tags: c, macros

I want to create a large number of declarations of static arrays, each with a different (static) size. I also want to be able to create an instance of all of them, and access them easily just with their ID. Can this be done with macros in C ?

i.e. I want to shorten this code

```
int array_1[SIZE_1];
int array_2[SIZE_2];
int array_3[SIZE_3];
int array_4[SIZE_4];
int array_5[SIZE_5];
int array_6[SIZE_6];
.
.
.
int array_40[SIZE_40];
```

and create this code (where the parts between `<>` are the ones I hope macros can do for me).

```
int StoreInArray(int array_id, int position, int value)
{
    if(position < SIZE_<array_id>)
    {
         array_<array_id>[position] = value;
         return 0;
    }
    else
    {
         return 1;
    }
}
```

Of note : memory imprint is important. I really want to have each array be exactly the size that it must be, and no more - unless a cheap solution is offered.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using one 2-dimensional array? Edit: nevermind, i just saw that it is not meant to be "rectangular".

Comment: There are ways to use the preprocessor iteratively to create numerous definitions, although unbounded repetition is not a feature of macro replacement. (Some unbounded repetition can be implemented via `#include`.) However, doing so may be an abuse of the preprocessor. Simply write other code, in C or your preferred scripting language, to generate the definitions, execute that code during build time, and include its output in your program using `#include`.

Comment: I could post an evil macro doing what you ask, but that isn't doing you a favour. The correct solution is probably to create a bunch of structs instead, each containing a pointer to an array and a size. Then declare an array of such structs.

Comment: Care to be more specific ? I will edit my post to say that memory imprint is important and that I cannot declare arrays with the max possible size but only use less than that for this particular array.

Comment: @Charles I posted an answer containing one good (what you should use) and one bad (what you are asking for) suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution is likely to reconsider your overall program design and instead do something like this:

```
typedef struct
{
  int*   data;
  size_t size;
} array_t;

const array_t array [40] = 
{
  { some_array, 3 },
  { some_other_array, 5 },
  ...
};
```

---

A much worse idea is to implement an evil macro. It might look like this:

```
// NOT RECOMMENDED
#define StoreInArray(id,pos,val) (pos < SIZE_##id ? (array_##id[pos] = val,1) : 0)
```

Where the parameter `id` is an integer constant such as `1`. Token concatenation then forms `SIZE_1`, `array_1` etc as the macro is expanded.

This is written as a function-like macro only assigning to the array if `pos` is smaller than the array size. If so, the macro returns `1` otherwise `0`. The comma operator is used inside the conditional operator `?:` to achieve this.

Example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE_1 4
#define SIZE_2 2
#define SIZE_3 5

int array_1[SIZE_1];
int array_2[SIZE_2];
int array_3[SIZE_3];

#define StoreInArray(id,pos,val) (pos < SIZE_##id ? (array_##id[pos] = val,1) : 0)

int main(void)
{
  if(StoreInArray(1, 3, 123))
  {
    printf("%d\n", array_1[3]); // prints 123
  }

  if(StoreInArray(1, 4, 123))
  {
    printf("%d\n", array_1[3]); // doesn't get executed
  }

  if(StoreInArray(3, 4, 456))
  {
    printf("%d\n", array_3[4]); // prints 456
  }
}
```

Comment: The evil macro addresses the second half of the question, but not the first. Is it possible to reduce the declaration of all the arrays using another, potentially even more evil macro ?

Comment: As far as the first, supposedly good solution is concerned : so I still have to declare `some_array`, `some_other_array`, etc... manually ? Also imperfect when you have dozens of them ...

Comment: @Charles Regarding declaration, yes you can trivially declare them all through "X macros". I don't see why it's such a big fuzz to declare a dozen arrays manually. The average computer program has hundreds, if not thousands of variables. DRY (don't repeat yourself) is a dangerous rule in many circumstances and often leads to obfuscation and needless complexity, which in turn leads to bugs and maintenance problems. Always go with KISS over DRY - truly skilled programmers always seek to make their programs more simple instead of more complicated.

Comment: It's not a dozen, it's dozens - currently 47, and it may evolve to be more than that. But yes, declaration is not that bad, all things considered - it's the individual access functions that kill me. But I can auto-generate them and keep that in a separate file for code clarity.

Comment: @Charles If you adapted some generic struct type as suggested here, then one single function could handle all cases.